# Sierpinski recursion issue with order triangles are drawn

Tags: python, recursion, turtle-graphics, fractals

This is the code for the [Sierpinski triangle](https://runestone.academy/runestone/static/pythonds/Recursion/pythondsSierpinskiTriangle.html), I just changed the degree variable to 2 (in the initial `sierpinsky()` call in `main()`) from the original text and I am running it using Python 3.5:

```
import turtle

def drawTriangle(points,color,myTurtle):
    myTurtle.fillcolor(color)
    myTurtle.up()
    myTurtle.goto(points[0][0],points[0][1])
    myTurtle.down()
    myTurtle.begin_fill()
    myTurtle.goto(points[1][0],points[1][1])
    myTurtle.goto(points[2][0],points[2][1])
    myTurtle.goto(points[0][0],points[0][1])
    myTurtle.end_fill()

def getMid(p1,p2):
    return ( (p1[0]+p2[0]) / 2, (p1[1] + p2[1]) / 2)

def sierpinski(points,degree,myTurtle):
    colormap = ['blue','red','green','white','yellow',
                'violet','orange']
    drawTriangle(points,colormap[degree],myTurtle)
    if degree > 0:
        sierpinski([points[0],
                        getMid(points[0], points[1]),
                        getMid(points[0], points[2])],
                   degree-1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([points[1],
                        getMid(points[0], points[1]),
                        getMid(points[1], points[2])],
                   degree-1, myTurtle)
        sierpinski([points[2],
                        getMid(points[2], points[1]),
                        getMid(points[0], points[2])],
                   degree-1, myTurtle)

def main():
   myTurtle = turtle.Turtle()
   myWin = turtle.Screen()
   myPoints = [[-100,-50],[0,100],[100,-50]]
   sierpinski(myPoints,2,myTurtle)
   myWin.exitonclick()

main()
```

When I run this code I can clearly see that the turtle draws the first inside triangle on the left at the first recursive call:

```
sierpinski([points[0], getMid(points[0], points[1]), getMid(points[0], points[2])], 1, myTurtle)
```

and then it proceeds to draw the left, top and right triangles inside that one in that order. So far so good.

Then the next triangle to be drawn is the one on top(of the bigger triangle) with the call:

```
sierpinski([points[1], getMid(points[0], points[1]), getMid(points[1], points[2])], 1, myTurtle)
```

Here is where it gets confusing, I expect the recursion to start drawing the bottom left triangle inside that triangle first. But it doesn't, it starts by drawing the top one.

When I run this dummy code that mimics the recursion in the code above:

```
def sierpinski(points,degree):
    print(points + " " + str(degree))
    if degree > 0:
        sierpinski("bottom left triangle", degree-1)
        sierpinski("top triangle", degree-1)
        sierpinski("bottom right triangle", degree-1)


sierpinski("start", 2)
```

The output is:

```
start 2

bottom left triangle 1

bottom left triangle 0

top triangle 0

bottom right triangle 0

top triangle 1

bottom left triangle 0

top triangle 0

bottom right triangle 0

bottom right triangle 1

bottom left triangle 0

top triangle 0

bottom right triangle 0
```

We can clearly see the order the triangles are drawn in is respected. Can you guys tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your triangles to draw clockwise from lower left, you need to define your points clockwise from lower left.  That's not what you did:

```
# clockwise from lower left:
[points[0], getMid(points[0], points[1]), getMid(points[0], points[2])]

# counter-clockwise from top:
[points[1], getMid(points[0], points[1]), getMid(points[1], points[2])]

# counter-clockwise from lower right:
[points[2], getMid(points[2], points[1]), getMid(points[0], points[2])]
```

Here's my rework that draws all the triangles clockwise from the lower left.  I also threw in some other code changes for you to think about:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle, Vec2D

COLORMAP = ['blue', 'red', 'green', 'white', 'yellow', 'violet', 'orange']

def drawTriangle(points, color, turtle):
    turtle.fillcolor(color)

    turtle.up()
    turtle.goto(points[0])
    turtle.down()

    turtle.begin_fill()
    turtle.goto(points[1])
    turtle.goto(points[2])
    turtle.goto(points[0])
    turtle.end_fill()

def getMid(p1, p2):
    return(p1 + p2) * 0.5

def sierpinski(points, degree, turtle):
    drawTriangle(points, COLORMAP[degree], turtle)

    if degree < 1:
        return

    sierpinski([points[0], getMid(points[0], points[1]), getMid(points[0], points[2])], degree - 1, turtle)
    sierpinski([getMid(points[0], points[1]), points[1], getMid(points[1], points[2])], degree - 1, turtle)
    sierpinski([getMid(points[0], points[2]), getMid(points[2], points[1]), points[2],], degree - 1, turtle)

def main():
    screen = Screen()
    yertle = Turtle()

    myPoints = [Vec2D(-100, -50), Vec2D(0, 100), Vec2D(100, -50)]
    sierpinski(myPoints, 2, yertle)

    yertle.hideturtle()
    screen.exitonclick()

main()
```

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful. Do you prefer to add the return statement to have an explicit base case ?

Comment: No, @d_darric, I can go either way.  In this case I did it to reduce the indentation of the long lines that follow.